# Select menu behaving differently

Tags: html, select-menu, multipleselection

When I add "multiple" attribute to select menu, it behaves differently & doesnt show all options in a drop down list.

How it looks:

[image]

Here's the html code:

```
<select name="advertLocation" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
    <option style="color:#3366cb;" value="Public - No specific target"><b>Public - No specific target</b></option>
    <option>Afghanistan</option>
    <option>Albania</option>
    ......
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have some CSS that may be involved?

Comment: What's your CSS?  This seems to work just fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/5QtXT/

Comment: in your fiddle, it doesn't show the drop-down menu

Comment: @JaskaranS.P, it does show a multiple select control in the lower right hand box. If you want something that will be closed in a neutral state and open when you click on it and then allow you to select multiple items and then close it again, you'll need something along the lines of Eric Hynds multiselect jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding `multiple="multiple"` and since you cannot select multiple values in a drop-down list, the browser renders the element as a scrolled list box.

There is nothing you can do to change this behaviour.

Comment: If by "solution" you mean "a way to make the browser render a `<select multiple...>` as a drop-down list" I am afraid there is none :)